# Persistent AR sessions in AR Core

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

In ARKit, Apple's augmented reality SDK, is possible to save and load enviroment understanding information. By this way, the user can experiment continuous sessions even when closing and opening the app.

My app idea is to save not only the enviroment information, but the anchors and elements. So, the user could develop his own mixed reality ambience through the time. The problem is that I need to do that in android phones, prefencialy using AR Core SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you are looking for is ARCore cloud anchors - these allow you save and share anchors between devices and sessions.

- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android

Its worth noting the deprecation policy in the documentation linked above also, and the APK levels you need to support Cloud Anchors.

Comment: Thank you! I found the Cloud Anchor, but I was searching for a offline solution...

Comment: Did you find any solution for offline anchor placement? I see in Android still there is only way to use save and share anchor's sessions is thru cloud anchors and no other solution seems available. Your reply is much appreciated. Thanks! @RafaelLadeia